# Codeigniter Get New Generated Username From Model To Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been struggling on this issue for a very long time and I still do not have any idea how to get this working.

Currently I need to show my new generated username from Model to Controller. But I can't seem to call it. Below is my code:

Model formval_callbacks.php :

```
public function _username_check( $user_name )
    {
        $this->db->select('user_name');
        $this->db->like('user_name', $user_name);
        $this->db->order_by('user_date', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $query->row();

            $db_username = $row->user_name;

            $username_counter = preg_match("/".$user_name."(\d+)/", $db_username, $matches) ? (int)$matches[1] : NULL;
            $username_counter++;

            return $user_name.$username_counter;
        }else{
            $username_counter = 1;
            return $user_name.$username_counter;
        }
    }
```

Model user_model.php :

```
public function create_user( $role, $insert_array = array() )
    {
        // The form validation class doesn't allow for multiple config files, so we do it the old fashion way
        $this->config->load( 'form_validation/administration/create_user/create_' . $role );
        $this->validation_rules = config_item( $role . '_creation_rules' );

        // If the data is already validated, there's no reason to do it again
        if( ! empty( $insert_array ) OR $this->validate() === TRUE )
        {
            // Prepare user_data array for insert into user table
            $user_data = array(
                'user_name'  => ( isset( $insert_array['user_name'] ) ) ? $insert_array['user_name'] : set_value('user_name'),
                'user_pass'  => ( isset( $insert_array['user_pass'] ) ) ? $insert_array['user_pass'] : set_value('user_pass'),
                'user_email' => ( isset( $insert_array['user_email'] ) ) ? $insert_array['user_email'] : set_value('user_email')
            );

            // User level derived directly from the role argument
            $user_data['user_level'] = $this->authentication->levels[$role];

            // If we are using form validation for the user creation
            if( empty( $insert_array ) )
            {
                // Remove some user_data elements from _field_data array as prep for insert into profile table
                $this->form_validation->unset_field_data( array(
                    'user_name',
                    'user_pass',
                    'user_email'
                ));

                // Create array of profile data
                foreach( $this->form_validation->get_field_data() as $k => $v )
                {
                    $profile_data[$k] = $v['postdata'];
                }

                // Unset all data for set_value(), so we can create another user
                $this->kill_set_value();
            }

            // If we are not using form validation for the user creation
            else
            {
                // Remove some insert_array elements as prep for insert into profile table
                unset( $insert_array['user_name'] );
                unset( $insert_array['user_pass'] );
                unset( $insert_array['user_email'] );

                // Profile data is insert array
                $profile_data = $insert_array;
            }

            // Encrypt any sensitive data
            if( isset( $profile_data['license_number'] ) )
            {
                $this->load->library('encrypt');
                $profile_data['license_number'] = $this->encrypt->encode( $profile_data['license_number'] );
            }

            // Create a random user id if not already set
            $random_unique_int = $this->get_unused_id();

            // Generate random user salt
            $user_salt = $this->authentication->random_salt();

            // Perform transaction
            $this->db->trans_start();

            $user_data['user_id']       = $random_unique_int;
            $user_data['user_pass']     = $this->authentication->hash_passwd( $user_data['user_pass'], $user_salt );
            $user_data['user_salt']     = $user_salt;
            $user_data['user_date']     = time();
            $user_data['user_modified'] = time();

            // Insert data in user table
            $this->db->set($user_data)
                        ->insert( config_item('user_table'));

            $profile_data['user_id'] = $random_unique_int;

            // Insert data in profile table
            $this->db->set($profile_data)
                        ->insert( config_item( $role . '_profiles_table'));

            // Complete transaction
            $this->db->trans_complete();

            // Verify transaction was successful
            if( $this->db->trans_status() !== FALSE )
            {
                // Load var to confirm user inserted into database
                $this->load->vars( array( 'user_created' => 1 ) );
            }

            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

Controller register.php :

```
public function index()
    {
        // Load resources
        $this->load->library('csrf');
        $this->load->model('registration_model');

        $reg_mode = $this->registration_model->get_reg_mode();

        // Check to see if there was a registration submission
        if( $this->csrf->token_match )
        {
            // If mode #1, registration allows for instant user creation without verification or approval.
            if( $reg_mode == 1 )
            {
                $_POST['user_level'] = 1;

                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $this->user_model->create_user( 'customer', array() );

                $this->load->model('formval_callbacks');
                $view_data['new_username'] = $this->formval_callbacks->_username_check();

            }

        }

        // If for some reason the user is already logged in
        $this->is_logged_in();

        // Send registration mode to view
        $view_data['reg_mode'] = $reg_mode;

        // Ouput alert-bar message if cookies not enabled
        $this->check_cookies_enabled();

        $data = array(
            'title' => WEBSITE_NAME . ' - Account Registration',
            'content' => $this->load->view( 'public/register/registration_form', $view_data, TRUE ),

            // Load the show password script
            'javascripts' => array(
                'js/jquery.passwordToggle-1.1.js',
                'js/jquery.char-limiter-3.0.0.js',
                'js/default-char-limiters.js'
            ),

            // Use the show password script
            'extra_head' => '
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#show-password").passwordToggle({target:"#user_pass"});
                    });
                </script>
            '
        );

        $this->load->view( $this->template, $data );
    }
```

There is an error for this line because I never put in any parameters : 
`$view_data['new_username'] = $this->formval_callbacks->_username_check();`

What should I do if I just want to get the new generated username without putting in the parameter?

Also, is it better to get the new generated username from formval_callback.php or user_model.php in this function :

```
if( $this->db->trans_status() !== FALSE )
```

Hope you guys can help me out here.

Comment: Hi Reza, the $user_name input is actually gotten from the username form field.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't handle user model related tasks in the user model but instead in "forval_callbacks"? If you had the user model data inside the user model you wouldn't have to wonder how to access it.

Comment: Hi Malte, actually I have downloaded this from the project name CommunityAuth which is using CodeIgniter. I am trying to make some changes to suit my needs but apparently I keep getting errors here and there as I am still new to CodeIgniter. Actually the formval_callbacks.php is a callback function for the form field validation : 'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha|strtolower|min_length['. MIN_CHARS_4_USERNAME .']|external_callbacks[model,formval_callbacks,_username_check]'

Comment: Since the create_user function doesn't save the user data, you could extend it to do so. Eg add a public var $last_created_user and set it inside the create_user function: $this->last_created_user=$profile_data. Then you can access its content by $this->user_model->last_created_user. In your example that would be $view_data['new_username']=$this->user_model->last_created_user['user_name']

Comment: Hi Malte, "Eg add a public var $last_created_user", how do I do for this?

Comment: Hi Malte, it's ok! I have changed your code $this->last_created_user=$profile_data to $this->last_created_user=$user_data and it works. Thanks for your help!